# USB host driver for PL2303 with Microchip USB stack

Tags: microchip, usb-host, pic24f

My goal of the project is to establish communication between
PIC24FJ32GU202(USB host) <--> PL2303SA(USB device).
I have configured the PIC24 as USB host and with help from examples, MCU can detect PL2303 but cannot communicate.

Issue:

As I found the hard way that PL2303 USB devices do not support traditional COM port (CDC class), rather additional drivers are required to communicate with it. Problem is there is no documentation for PL2303. So I used USBCap with Wireshark to read communication between PC and PL2303, then replicated it in Microchip USB stack, but communication is not successful.

> control read data :- `C0 01 84 84 00 00 01 00`

> error occurring:- `invalid packet id received`

Can anyone help with what I might be doing wrong or share a similar implementation of USB host?

Comment: Linux has a driver for Prolific chipset. Can you use that as a reference instead of reverse-engineering yourself?

Comment: I looked at the Linux driver, packet data exchanged after communication are same from USB cap trace, my issue is that USB device does not reply to the packet.

Comment: After DEVICE ATTACH is done, host sends multiple CONTROL transfer packets to which device should reply correct data. Error packet id received is 00, which means no reply from device.

Comment: It's a bit surprising to attach a USB-to-UART bridge to a microcontroller's USB port; are you running out of UARTs in your microcontroller?

Comment: The application requires communication with USB port, it can be PC, android with otg cable or the embedded host on MCU.